# Minecraft closes whenever I alt tab from full screen

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Every time I attempt to get out of Minecraft (i.e alt tab, windows key) it closes. if I go to windowed mode, this doesn't happen. How do I stop this?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this, but I have a Windows 8 computer and this is how I get out:

- Press <kbd>F8</kbd>
- Press <kbd>F10</kbd>
- Press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> and Minimize.
- Press the Windows key and go back to desktop.

There are a bunch of other ways to do this, but I find there the quickest and most useful. If you DON'T have the same keyboard as I do, then... you're out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to prevent this is to play in windowed mode.

If you're on Windows, you can try installing the [borderless mining](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/borderless-mining) mod to remove the window's borders, making it play almost the same as full-screen, but without it minimizing when it loses focus.

Otherwise you have to wait until [MC-158117](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-158117) is fixed.

Comment: Just playing windowed with maximized window isn't so bad either. In higher resolutions the border takes up very little.

Answer (score -1):

f11 to get out of fullscreen, if thats what you mean.

Comment: That's not what he means.